# I cant access certain resources (URL Parameters) java

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm creating a banking app in Java using jersey, jaxrb, maven a jpa objecet.

I have a customer section which works fine. I can access via /customer and return all customers or /customers/238349 and return that specific customer.

The issues arise when I attempt to use my account section. I have 3 files Account (model), Account service (creates services like check balance) and resource (Allows access to services via param).

If i create another resource I can access it just fine. So I think the issue lies in the AccountResource file. If i delete everything out of the resource file and add a method that print the last param out in works.

So account/hello etc.

Any ideas. I'M REALLT STUCK

Comment: What specific error do you get? An exception, or some wrong result? If you get some wrong result, what do you do, what do you expect to get and what do you get instead?

Comment: I believe the @Produces is not in the right place. I think it needs to be placed at the start of each method defining what that method produces.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Hi, and thanks for the reply. I get a 404 error. If i type i use the url /balance/210590. With the number being the customer id. I want the balance of that customer.

Comment: Nevermind. It can be applied to class and method both. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrns/index.html

Comment: Thanks @clinomaniac. Any idea what the issue could be? Does my database look ok?

Comment: Did you try `/accounts/balance/210590`? That class-mapped `@Path` defines a prefix for method mappings.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy I did. Now I'm getting a 500 error. I changed the line in the service from CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(Account.class); to CriteriaQuery cq = Accountcb.createQuery(Account.class); That's some progress anyway

Answer (score 1):

You should GET from `/accounts/balance/210590` and not from `/balance/210590` as that `@Path("/accounts")` on your class defines a prefix for method mappings.

Comment: Thanks. I realise that. I made a typo. However I have an erro 500 now, the 404 is gone. So i'm trying to debug that

Comment: Roman posted this as the answer because this is the answer to your question. If you have another issue then you can ask another question. A 500 error can be very general. It means something went wrong. Try to look at the logs to see if your services are behaving correctly. Try to run local tests to see if the methods work as expected.